# smali structure of methods and classes

Tags: java, android, dalvik, dex, smali

I have recently dug into some smali code and would love learning it. I have checked the dalvik bytecode reference but I couldn't find a structure reference as to when/how to use these

```
.locals
.local
.registers
.prologue
.line
.annotation
.parameter
```

Do you know other resources to explain more of the smali structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these, with the exception of .locals, .registers and .annotation, are a part of the debug information that is stored as part of a method. You can find more information about these in the debug_info_item section in the [dex-format](http://s.android.com/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html) document.

For the .locals and .registers directive, these are two different ways you can specify the number of registers that are available in the method (i.e. the registers_size field of the code_item, as per the [dex-format](http://s.android.com/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html) document). You can find more information about the differences between the two on the [Registers wiki page](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki/Registers) on the smali googlecode site.

And finally, the .annotation directive defines an annotation. You can find more information in the [dex-format](http://s.android.com/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html) document. Specifically, you'll want to look at the following items:

- annotations_directory_item: contains references to all the class, method, field and parameter annotations for a class
- annotation_set_ref_list: contains references to the annotations associated with the parameters for a method
- annotation_set_item: contains a list of annotations that can be associated with a method, field or class
- encoded_annotation: stores a single annotation

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks! I knew you would be the first one to answer these questions. I hope you'll be able to answer questions as I keep posting them here.